# Visual Basic 6 VB Overriding a Function

Tags: vb6

I recently started using vb6 to make a simple exe and I can't figure out how to get "Overrides" to work.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean

End Function
```

This gives me a "expected: end of statement" error and it highlights "Function". It is typed exactly how I've been seeing it in examples so I'm not sure what is wrong. I am typing this into my Form1 class. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a VB.NET function. VB6 doesn't support Protected or Overrides.

Comment: Kelly is correct. You copied some piece of code you found on the internet, but it's for VB.NET. If you want to find VB6 code, the easiest way is to search for VBA code. There's still some difference, but VB6 & VBA are (at a guess) 90% the same. VB6 & VB.NET are maybe 50% (if that).